# How to set up the inverse search for LaTeXTools in Sublime Text 3 on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, sublime-text

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

TexLive (including `latexmk`) was installed successfully. The pdf reader is  `evince` by default. Compiling `tex` files inside ST3 works perfectly. The forward search also works. But I simply can't get the inverse search right, i.e. `ctrl+left click` on the pdf file doesn't have any response. Can anyone share his/her settings for LaTeXTools? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with CTRL + Left click?

Comment: The inverse search. Doing so is supposed to take me to the position in the tex file that corresponds to the place I click in the pdf file.

Answer (score 5):

I wasn't aware of Sublime Text, but seems nice.

In order to get the inverse search, open

Preferences > Package Settings > LaTeXTools > Settings -- User

Scroll down and replace `"sublime": "sublime-text"` for `"sublime": "subl"`

[image: Sublime Text]

Now it should work. Ctrl + click on evince. Instructions were [here](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools).

Comment: Yes. I went through LaTeXTools' documentation and set the configuration file as you posted. It turns out that for the inverse search to work, LaTeXTools calls `python` and utilizes the `dbus` module, as discussed [here](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/330). Apparently, I had another `python` (Anaconda distribution) installed on my machine and the module `dbus` isn't included in it. Once I set the path to the `python` that comes with Ubuntu, the problem goes away.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Ludenticus answer: With ubuntu 14.10 and sublime3, I also needed to set

```
"python2": "/usr/bin/python"
```

under `platform settings -> linux` in order to get backward search working in evince.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to setting the correct `subl` and `python2` commands, `python2` bindings to `dbus` are needed (as mentioned by @William Zhang in the comments).

On Ubuntu 16.04 the package `python-dbus` provides these, and does *not* seem to be installed by default.